# Laravel pass controller database query to view

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display a query in a view. Each result I want to be a submit button that would submit his value when clicked.

In **ListController** I have this code:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $tables = DB::table('tables')->select('name')->get();

        return view('welcome', compact('tables'));
    }
```

In **welcome.blade.php** I have:

```
            <form action="{{ route('get_table') }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                @foreach($tables as  $data)
                <input type="submit" name="tables[]" value="{{ $data }}">
                @endforeach
            </form>
```

In routes **web.php** I have:

```
Route::get('/', 'ListController@index');
```

And I get this error:

```
"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View:...welcome.blade.php)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` is an object, despite you only selecting one column. You have two options:

Use the name property for `$data`:

```
<input type="submit" name="tables[]" value="{{ $data->name }}">
```

Or use `pluck` to retrieve a collection of single names.

```
$tables = DB::table('tables')->pluck('name');
```